# Retornando dados vinculados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

Com a ajuda e Milrak Pereira Pessoa e do Wéllingthon M. de Souza, editei meu código... Eu tenho um código de produto e ele possui 5 tipos e 5 descricoes. Estou tentando trazer para o usuário os tipos e descrições dentro da tabela em branco. Porém, da forma que estou tentando ele adiciona linhas abaixo da tabela que só possui 5 linhas como na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foto 1 => Registros no banco de dados, queria que os numeros fossem retornados dentro de uma tabela para exibi-los para o usuário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

index.php

```
<!-- Inicio do script criado para função de completar próximos campos -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[name='descri']").blur(function(){
                    var $codigo_produto = $("input[name='codigo_produto']");
                    var $id = $("input[name='id']");
                    var $codigo_tipo = $("input[name='codigo_tipo[]']");
                    var $descricao = $("input[name='descricao[]']");                       

                    $.getJSON('function.php',{ 
                            descricao: $( this ).val() 
                    },function( json ){
                            var html = "";
                                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                                  html += '<tr>';
                                    html += '<td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'+json[i].codigo_produto+'"></td>';
                                    html += '<td><input type="text" name="codigo_tipo[]" value="'+json[i].codigo_tipo+'" /></td>';
                                    html += '<td><input type="text" name="descricao[]" value="'+json[i].descricao+'" /></td>';
                                  html += '</tr>';
                                }

                            $("table tbody").append(html);
                    });
            });
    });
</script>  
<!-- Fim do script -->

<form action='salvar.php' method='POST'>   

    <div class='form-group col-lg-4'>
        <label>  <b>Descrição:</b> </label> <!-- Não é enviado para o banco só está sendo utilizado para preencher os campos a partir deste -->
        <input type="text" maxlength="20"  name="descri"><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group col-lg-4'>
        <label>  <b>Código do Produto:</b> </label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="15"  name="codigo_produto"><br><br>
    </div>

    <table border="2"><!-- Iniciando a Tabela -->

        <thead>
            <tr><!-- Início dos Títulos da Tabela / Cabeçalho -->
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>                                                                                                              
            </tr><!-- Fim dos Títulos da Tabela / Cabeçalho -->
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){ //coloquei este valor para testar ?>        
                <tr>
                    <?php              
                        $sql_tipo = "SELECT * FROM tipoprod ";
                        $resulta = $conn->query($sql_tipo);
                        $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();
                            echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
                    ?> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="codigo_tipo[]"</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="descricao[]" </td> 

                </tr>
           <?php } ?>
        </tbody>

    </table><br>
```

function.php

```
  <?php
include_once("conn.php");

function retorna($descricao, $conn){

    $result = "SELECT A.descricao, A.codigo_produto, B.codigo_tipo, B.descricao FROM CADPRO A "
            . " LEFT OUTER JOIN TIPOPROD B ON (A.CODIGO_PRODUTO = B.CODIGO_PRODUTO) WHERE A.descricao= '$descricao' ";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

    // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
    $valores = array();

    if($resultado){
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

            $novo['codigo_produto'] = $row['codigo_produto'];
            $novo['codigo_tipo'] = $row['codigo_tipo'];
            $novo['descricao'] = $row['descricao'];

            array_push($valores, $novo);
        }

    } else {
        return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
    }

    return json_encode($valores);                
}

if(isset($_GET['descricao'])){
    echo retorna($_GET['descricao'], $conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o retorno `json`

Comment: o retorno que estou tendo dentro da aba network ? vou editar e colocar

Comment: Você quer que substitui os dados já existentes na tabela ? Ou adicionar as linhas no final da tabela ?

Comment: eu quero que ao usuário digitar a descrição do produto, ela retorne o codigo do produto e também os tipos e descricoes vinculados a ele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve remover a linha

```
print_r($valores);
```

do arquivo `function.php` e depois tratar o retorno.

```
var html = ""; 
$.getJSON('functionx.php',{ 
    descricao: $( this ).val() 
},function( json ){
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'+json[i].codigo_produto+'"></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="codigo_tipo[]" value="'+json[i].codigo_tipo+'" /></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="descricao[]" value="'+json[i].descricao+'" /></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    $("table tbody").html(html);
});
```

> Podes ver no [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/reroyafeqo/edit?js,output)

Comment: Alterei o código desta forma e o retorno do Json só vai para a aba Network e nada de completar na tela, que estranho, e no jsbin é justamente o que eu quero. Vou editar para mostrar como ficou a function

Comment: Remove a linha `print_r($valores);` do arquivo `function.php`

Comment: ok, fiz a edição com o JavaScript alterado e a o arquivo function.php também

Comment: Mesmo assim não funcionou ?

Comment: Funcionou, só que ele cria as linhas abaixo da tabela postei um print, ela quando esta vazia vem com 5 linhas em branco como no Jsbin do seu exemplo, porém quando a função é acionada/executada. Ocorre isso que postei no print

Comment: No *JSBin* ela esta retornando com os valores do `json` não esta vazio

Comment: acho que não soube me expressar, a tabela antes de eu digitar qualquer coisa ela ja vem em branco com 5 linhas, e ai quando executo a função, invés de ela preencher os campos em branco ela cria 5 campos preenchidos a mais embaixo das 5 linhas em branco

Comment: Veja agora, se esta certo.

Comment: Agora ele não cria outros 5 campos mas, está trazendo apenas o último registro em todas linhas

Comment: Bom, voltei como antes, mais agora troquei `$("table tbody").append(html);` para `$("table tbody").html(html);`

Comment: Agora deu certo cara, muito obrigado de coração apanhei o dia todo pra isso. Sou iniciante em JavaScript e PHP, desculpe por encomodar tanto, vou marcar como a melhor resposta sem dúvidas

Answer (score 1):

Só retorna um erro por conta so seu While:

```
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){         
     $valores['codigo_produto'] = $row['codigo_produto'];
     $valores['id'] = $row['id'];
     $valores['codigo_tipo'] = $row['codigo_tipo'];
     $valores['descricao'] = $row['descricao'];
    }
```

Toda vez que ele dá uma "volta", ele sobrescreve a informação anterior.

Mude para:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))

        $novo['codigo_produto'] = $row['codigo_produto'];
        $novo['id'] = $row['id'];
        $novo['codigo_tipo'] = $row['codigo_tipo'];
        $novo['descricao'] = $row['descricao'];

        array_push($valores, $novo);
    }

    print_r($valores);
```

E corre para o abraço!

Comment: Obrigado, estou perto agora com sua ajuda, vou atualizar o código do arquivo functionx.php para você verificar. Porque dentro do Inspecionar => aba Network  tenho o retorno dos dados em array mas, não são trazidos na tela para o usuário