# Criar uma array apartir de 2 outras arrays

Tags: php

Tenho duas tabelas distintas, que estão em base de dados distintos, e preciso de uma array com as informações unificadas.

Exemplo:

```
Cadastro de Fornecedores ( ID_For, ID_Pes, STATUS )

Cadastro de Pessoas ( ID_Pes, NOME, FANTASIA, CPF/CNPJ, ... )
```

Preciso de uma array como abaixo:

```
For_Pessoa = ( ID_For, ID_Pes, STATUS, NOME, FANTASIA, CPF/CNPJ, ....)
```

Obs: Lembrando que na junção o `ID_Pes` tem que coincidir, a array de Pessoas só contem os dados dos fornecedores. ( usado "IN" do `Fornecedores->ID_Pes` )

Comment: Pq no retorno dessa query vc ja não monta um join para ter o retorno direto que vc procura ?

Comment: Vinicius boas, 

Eu uso um Framework, e dentro deste uso classes de objetos para acesso as tabelas, e no meu caso em especifico criei uma classe especifica para acessar as tabelas em base distintas.

Esta Classe ela me retorna uma array dos objetos selecionados, assim tenho 2 arrays com os referidos objetos. e quero unifica-los.

Comment: Detalhe - Tabelas em Base de Dados diferentes e servidores diferentes

Comment: Você já consegue obter os *arrays*, resta apenas juntá-los? Já tentou a função [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)?

Comment: Entendi, vc pode usar o `array_push ` do php dentro de um lanço `foreach` e com um `if` especificar para relacionar os campos, eu até poderia elaborar uma resposta melhor mas no momento estou ocupado , se ainda n tiverem mandado a resposta eu envio mais tarde

Comment: isso mesmo já tenho as duas arrays, preciso apenas ajunta-las, mas respeitando o ID_Pes das duas arrays, que eh o elo de ligação.
Sei que via programação eu teria varias formas de faze-lo, como exemplo, num laço da array pessoas,  acessar a tabela de fornecedores e incrementar as informações faltantes, mas isto seria dispendioso. 
Como já tenho as duas informações, quero uni-las sem criar um funil.

Anderson boas, o array_merge ele adiciona no final a outra array, que não eh o meu caso.

Comment: Vinicius boas, o array_push tem funcionamento parecido com o array_merge. mas a sua ideia do if e valido. estou aqui pensando com os meus botões..:)

Answer (score 0):

Como citado nos comentários, você pode fazer uma condição, veja esse é um exemplo, pode ter outros.

```
$Fornecedores = [
  [ 'ID_For' => 1, 'ID_Pes' => 1, 'STATUS' => 1 ],
  [ 'ID_For' => 2, 'ID_Pes' => 2, 'STATUS' => 2 ],
  [ 'ID_For' => 3, 'ID_Pes' => 3, 'STATUS' => 3 ],
];
$Pessoas = [
  [
    'ID_Pes' => 1,
    'NOME' => 'Pessoa 1',
    'FANTASIA' => 'Fantasia 1',
    'CPF/CNPJ' => '111.111.111-11'
  ],
  [
    'ID_Pes' => 2,
    'NOME' => 'Pessoa 2',
    'FANTASIA' => 'Fantasia 2',
    'CPF/CNPJ' => '222.222.222-22'
  ],
  [
    'ID_Pes' => 3,
    'NOME' => 'Pessoa 3',
    'FANTASIA' => 'Fantasia 3',
    'CPF/CNPJ' => '333.333.333-33'
  ],
];

$For_Pessoa = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($Fornecedores); $i++) {
  // Verifica se ID_Pes de ambos são iguais
  if ($Fornecedores[$i]['ID_Pes'] == $Pessoas[$i]['ID_Pes']) {
    // Combina os dois resultados e gurda na variável.
    $ForPessoa = array_merge($Fornecedores[$i], $Pessoas[$i]);
    // Adiciona na nova Array
    array_push($For_Pessoa, $ForPessoa);
  }
}

print_r($For_Pessoa);
```

A saída será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID_For] => 1
            [ID_Pes] => 1
            [STATUS] => 1
            [NOME] => Pessoa 1
            [FANTASIA] => Fantasia 1
            [CPF/CNPJ] => 111.111.111-11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID_For] => 2
            [ID_Pes] => 2
            [STATUS] => 2
            [NOME] => Pessoa 2
            [FANTASIA] => Fantasia 2
            [CPF/CNPJ] => 222.222.222-22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID_For] => 3
            [ID_Pes] => 3
            [STATUS] => 3
            [NOME] => Pessoa 3
            [FANTASIA] => Fantasia 3
            [CPF/CNPJ] => 333.333.333-33
        )

)
```

> Podes ver funcionando aqui no [repl.it](https://repl.it/MzJs/1)

Comment: não quero criar outra pergunta, poderia me ajudar nesta dúida  sobre array ? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248059/retornando-dados-vinculados

Answer (score 0):

Vamos simular sua solução conforme o exemplo que você passou, acredito que exista uma forma mais otimizada é somente uma das possibilidades de implementação.

```
<?php

$cadastro_forncedor = [];
$cadastro_pessoa    = [];
$for_pessoa         = [];

// For_Pessoa = ( ID_For, ID_Pes, STATUS, NOME, FANTASIA, CPF/CNPJ, ....)
// while($row = $res->fetch()) {
//     $id_for = $row['id_for'];
//     $id_pes = $row['id_pes'];
//     $status = $row['status'];
//     //( ID_For, ID_Pes, STATUS )
//     $cadastro_forncedor[$id_for] = ["id_pes" => $id_pes, "status" => $status];
// }

$cadastro_forncedor["1"] = ["id_pes" => 10, "status" => "ativo"];
$cadastro_forncedor["2"] = ["id_pes" => 20, "status" => "ativo"];
$cadastro_forncedor["3"] = ["id_pes" => 30, "status" => "ativo"];

print_r($cadastro_forncedor);

// saida
// Array
// (
//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [id_pes] => 10
//             [status] => ativo
//         )

//     [2] => Array
//         (
//             [id_pes] => 20
//             [status] => ativo
//         )

//     [3] => Array
//         (
//             [id_pes] => 30
//             [status] => ativo
//         )

// )

// 
// while($row = $res->fetch()) {
//     $id_pes     = $row['id_pes'];
//     $nome       = $row['nome'];
//     $fantasia   = $row['fantasia'];
//     $cpf_cnpj   = $row['cpf_cnpj'];
//     // ID_Pes, NOME, FANTASIA, CPF/CNPJ
//     $cadastro_pessoa[$id_pes] = ["nome" => $nome, 
//               "fantasia" => $fantasia, 
//               "cpf_cnpj" => $cpf_cnpj];
// }

$cadastro_pessoa[10] = ["nome" => "Leo Caracciolo", 
              "fantasia" => "Caracciolo", 
              "cpf_cnpj" => "039.398.938-23"
          ];

$cadastro_pessoa[20] = ["nome" => "Vanessa", 
              "fantasia" => "Silva", 
              "cpf_cnpj" => "039.398.383-23"
          ];

$cadastro_pessoa[30] = ["nome" => "Maria", 
              "fantasia" => "Madalena", 
              "cpf_cnpj" => "039.476.383-23"
          ];


print_r($cadastro_pessoa);

//saida
// Array
// (
//     [10] => Array
//         (
//             [nome] => Leo Caracciolo
//             [fantasia] => Caracciolo
//             [cpf_cnpj] => 039.398.938-23
//         )

//     [20] => Array
//         (
//             [nome] => Vanessa
//             [fantasia] => Silva
//             [cpf_cnpj] => 039.398.383-23
//         )

//     [30] => Array
//         (
//             [nome] => Maria
//             [fantasia] => Madalena
//             [cpf_cnpj] => 039.476.383-23
//         )

// )

// 
// vamos agora preencher nosso vetor 
// com as informacoes que deseja
//
if(is_array($cadastro_forncedor)) {

    foreach ($cadastro_forncedor as $id_for => $arrayForn) {

        // print_r($arrayForn);

        $nome = isset($cadastro_pessoa[$arrayForn["id_pes"]]["nome"]) ? $cadastro_pessoa[$arrayForn["id_pes"]]["nome"] : "";
        $fantasia = isset($cadastro_pessoa[$arrayForn["id_pes"]]["fantasia"]) ? $cadastro_pessoa[$arrayForn["id_pes"]]["fantasia"] : "";
        $cpf_cnpj = isset($cadastro_pessoa[$arrayForn["id_pes"]]["cpf_cnpj"]) ? $cadastro_pessoa[$arrayForn["id_pes"]]["cpf_cnpj"] : "";

        // // ( ID_For, ID_Pes, STATUS, NOME, FANTASIA, CPF/CNPJ, ....)
        $for_pessoa[] = [

            "ID_For" => $id_for,
            "ID_Pes" => $arrayForn["id_pes"],
            "STATUS" => $arrayForn["status"],
            "NOME" => $nome,
            "FANTASIA" => $fantasia,
            "CPF_CNPJ" => $cpf_cnpj
        ];
    }

    print_r($for_pessoa);
}

// saida

// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [ID_For] => 1
//             [ID_Pes] => 10
//             [STATUS] => ativo
//             [NOME] => Leo Caracciolo
//             [FANTASIA] => Caracciolo
//             [CPF_CNPJ] => 039.398.938-23
//         )

//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [ID_For] => 2
//             [ID_Pes] => 20
//             [STATUS] => ativo
//             [NOME] => Vanessa
//             [FANTASIA] => Silva
//             [CPF_CNPJ] => 039.398.383-23
//         )

//     [2] => Array
//         (
//             [ID_For] => 3
//             [ID_Pes] => 30
//             [STATUS] => ativo
//             [NOME] => Maria
//             [FANTASIA] => Madalena
//             [CPF_CNPJ] => 039.476.383-23
//         )
// )
```

Copiando e colando você irá conseguir rodar o código acima e visualizar se cheguei perto da sua dúvida.

> [você pode executar aqui](https://repl.it/MzJs/2)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro quero pedir desculpas pelo retorno atrasado, semanas curtas e feriados longos :)).

Segundo agradecer a todos pela ajuda prestadas, foram de grande valia para a minha conclusão e solução. Por isso não escolhi uma, mas pontuei todas.(Não sei se fiz certo)

Terceiro Solução:

1 - Carreguei numa array todos os Fornecedores Ativos (STATUS), já que este tecnicamente e menor em qtde de registros (Base).

```
$Fors= array();
$Foreg = array();

if ( $Fors_db = "Usei Classe para fazer o Select e retornar a informação" )
{
   foreach( $Fors_db as $For )
   {
       $Fors[] = $For->FOR_PESSOAID;

       $Foreg[ $For->FOR_PESSOAID ] = $For;
   } 
} 
else $Fors[] = '0';
```

2 - Carreguei numa array todas as Pessoas, que tem vinculo com os Fornecedores  $Fors[], ou seja usei um (IN) no select. 
Num "foreach" carreguei um datagrid adicionando as informações do Fornecedor.

```
if ( $objects = "Usei Classe para fazer o Select e retornar a informação" )
{
    foreach ( $objects as $object )
    {
        $object->FOR_ID      = $Foreg[ $object->PES_ID ]->FOR_ID;
        $object->PES_TIPO    = $TpPess[ $object->PES_TIPO ];
        $object->PES_CPFCNPJ = TGeral::CpfCnpj( $object->PES_CPFCNPJ );
        $object->PES_CEP     = TGeral::Cep( $object->PES_CEP );
        $object->PES_STATUS  = $Foreg[ $object->PES_ID ]->FOR_STATUS;
        $object->PES_ULTIMA  = TDate::date2br( $object->PES_ULTIMA );

        datagrid->addItem( $object );
    }
}
```

Att.

MarcoARCampos.