# inner join mysql 2 tabelas

Tags: php, mysqli, join, inner

Estou precisando vincular duas tabelas e não estou conseguindo corrigir ou achar onde estou errando.

Tenho duas tabelas:

Tabela 1: br_regiao | id - iduf - nome  - (1 , 1, Litoral)

Tabela 2: br_estado | id - nome - (1 - Santa Catarina)

Consulta: campo **nome** e **iduf** da tabela **br_região** e campo **nome** da tabela **br_estado** fazendo um echo do campo **br_estado.nome** e **br_região.nome**

Erro : Só mostra o campo da tabela **br_estado.nome** e no campo **br_regiao.nome** não aparece nada.

PHP Codigo

```html
<tbody>
<?php                   
$query = mysqli_query($_mysqli,"select * from br_regiao inner join br_estado on br_regiao.iduf = br_estado.id order by br_regiao.id desc");
while ($categoria = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $categoria['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $categoria['br_estado.nome']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $categoria['br_regiao.nome']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm show-tooltip" title="Edit" href="<?php echo $URL_ADMIN; ?>regiao.php?id=<?php echo $categoria['.id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm show-tooltip" title="Delete" href="<?php echo $URL_ADMIN; ?>regiaoalt.php?id=<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando acessar 2 índices que não existem **br_estado.nome** e **br_regiao.nome**.

No retorno do **select** você está retornando 2 colunas, ambas tem o mesmo *nome/título*, diante disso o PHP irá gerar um índice para somente uma das colunas. Você pode constatar o que eu falei adicionando essa linha dentro do seu laço de repetição:

```
<td><?php echo $categoria['nome']; ?></td>
```

Para resolver este problema você pode trabalhar com ***alais*** para as colunas. Para facilitar fiz o seguinte:

- Criei um apelido para cada tabela, onde **br_regiao** virou **r** e **br_estado** virou **e**. Obviamente se a query fosse maior seria recomendado utilizar apelidos sugestivos para não nos perdermos no decorrer do select
- Posteriormente também atribui alias as colunas que são retornadas, para que tenham nomes distintos e o PHP possa gerar índices validos para o array de dados. Veja:

---

```
<tbody>
<?php                   
$query = mysqli_query($_mysqli,"select r.id, r.nome reg_nome, e.nome est_nome from br_regiao r inner join br_estado e on r.iduf = e.id order by r.id desc");

while ($categoria = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $categoria['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $categoria['est_nome']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $categoria['reg_nome']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm show-tooltip" title="Edit" href="<?php echo $URL_ADMIN; ?>regiao.php?id=<?php echo $categoria['.id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm show-tooltip" title="Delete" href="<?php echo $URL_ADMIN; ?>regiaoalt.php?id=<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

No retorno acima estou devolvendo somente o **id** da tabela de regiões. Caso seja necessário devolver também o **id** da tabela de estados, lembre-se de adicionar um alias em razão do nome das colunas serem iguais.

Comment: Muito obrigado Fábio Jânio, sua ajuda resolveu meu problema...

Comment: Sempre a disposição @LuisEstebanPastén

Comment: Fábio pode me ajudar ?@FábioJânio a resolver um problema de array, pela sua pontuação deverá entender... não quero criar outra pergunta, poderia me ajudar nesta dúida  sobre array ? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248059/retornando-dados-vinculados

Comment: Ok. De uma olhada lá, parece que um camarada já conseguiu identificar o problema. Mas vou acompanhar o tópico, qualquer coisa dependendo do seu Feedback na resposta do camarada eu tento ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

Altere seu código para este

```html
<?php 

$result = "SELECT A.id, A.id_uf, A.nome AS nome_regiao, B.id, B.nome AS nome_estado FROM BR_REGIAO A LEFT OUTER JOIN BR_ESTADO B ON (A.BR_REGIAO.IDUF = B.BR_ESTADO.ID) ORDER BY B.BR_REGIAO.ID DESC ";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $categoria['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $categoria['nome_estado']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $categoria['nome_regiao']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm show-tooltip" title="Edit" href="<?php echo $URL_ADMIN; ?>regiao.php?id=<?php echo $categoria['.id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm show-tooltip" title="Delete" href="<?php echo $URL_ADMIN; ?>regiaoalt.php?id=<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Obrigado Pela resposta Victor..
:)